# What regular expression can I use to pass GET variables via URL rewrite?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I know that I should pass variables through the structure of the url instead of passing them via GET, but I find myself in this situation where I already have a fixed URL structure, and I need to pass additional parameters that are needed only in certain particular cases, so are not always present in the request.
Since regexp's are one of my weak points, I could use some help..
What I have is:

> categories/10/category name.html?somevar=X&someothervar=Y

what I would need is:

> RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)/([^/]+).html**what should I put here?**$ somepage.php?section=cat&id=$1&name=$2&somevar=$3&someothervar=$4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need them in certain cases, don't rewrite them, but use the QSA modifier (Query String Append), which will let you keep the additional query string stuff.

Like:

```
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)/([^/]+).html$ somepage.php?section=cat&id=$1&name=$2 [QSA]
```

Using this, if `categories/10/categoryname.html?somevar=X&someothervar=Y` is requested, you will get the rewritten query vars as well as the additional ones in your app.